# Postback on link button when clicking to show modal box

Tags: c#, asp.net

I try to do a modal box update with new table after onclick button. Right now I'm using `asp:LinkButton`, so when user click this there will be sending `ID` to server side and search through database than update the modal box. Inside modal box I'm using `asp:UpdatePanel` with `UpdateMode="conditional"`.

The problem is, there is a postback after clicking those link button. Do you guys have suggestion for this problem. Or instead I using another method. Please help this newbie guys. Thanks.

Comment: try to keep linkbutton under update panel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Add ClientIdMode = "AutoId" in your page.
2) Register every LinkButton as an AsyncPostBackTrigger programmatically in the event ListView1_ItemDataBound.

```
protected void ListView1_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
{
LinkButton btnTaskTitle = e.Item.FindControl("TaskTitle") as LinkButton;
if btnTaskTitle != null)
ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this).RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(btnTaskTitle );
}
}
```

http://forums.asp.net/t/1859197.aspx?Linkbutton+within+a+ListView+that+is+within+an+UpdatePanel+causes+full+Postback+instead+of+AsyncPostBack